# simple modal with fullpage.js

Tags: modal-dialog, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js in several sections on my website. When I call a simple full-screen modal on section 2, 3, or higher it appears over  section 1 instead of the correct section.

My CSS is the following:

```
.modal-screen
position: fixed
width: 100%
height: 100%
left: 0
top: 0
z-index: 1
```

I would be very grateful for any help or suggestions!

Comment: It has been resolved with simple CSS. If the section class is relative while the modal is absolute it does work fine.